# Let $M$ be a smooth n-manifold($n\geq 1$).Prove that $M$ admits a diffeomorphism $f : M \to M$ which is not the identity

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I don't know how to come up with a proof for this. I think I have to come up with a bump function and do it locally on each chart and then extend it to the whole manifold??
May be I am wrong..

Thanks for any help

Comment: If this is true, I am shocked that I am my age and have never seen or thought of this before.

Comment: if $M$ is a point?

Comment: My intuition says that as long as $M$ is not a point, you can just remap some open ball in a coordinate neighborhood to itself via a diffeomorphism that fixes the boundary.

Comment: @AndresMejia Sorry $n \geq 1$

Comment: Hint: First construct a nonzero compactly supported vector field on $M$ (assuming $dim(M)>0$).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, I think I understand what you mean, as every compactly supported smooth vector field is complete. Hence we ll then get a global 1-parameter family of diffeomorphism. Does that what you mean?

Comment: Right...........

Comment: @jgon: How about fixing a neighborhood of the boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $n = \dim M \ge 1$.

The easiest way I know to see this is to pick any smooth, not-identically-zero section $X$ of $TM$, and consider its flow $\phi_X(x, t)$:

$\dot \phi_X(x, t) = X(\phi_X(x, t)); \tag 1$

we have

$\phi_X(x, 0) = x, \; \forall x \in M, \tag 2$

but it is easy to see from (1) (by if necessary using local coordinates near $x$) that if $X(x) \ne 0$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$

$\phi_X(x, \epsilon) \ne x. \tag 3$

Thus $\phi_X(x, \epsilon)$ is a non-identity diffeomorphism of $M$.

It appears that it is also possible, as the comment stream suggests, to pick a coordinate ball about some point and directly construct an appropriate diffeomorphism in that ball, a process which I think is also relatively straightforward.

Comment: You certainly cannot expect to get a non-vanishing vector field in general. All you need is a vector field that is not identically zero.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  yes, of course; I meant to convey exactly that.  Perhaps I will edit my post.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without vector fields.

Let us see first how the case $n=2$ is dealt. For any $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$, denote by $R_\theta$ the rotation matrix of $\mathbb R^2$ of angle $\theta$. Let $D^2$ be the unit closed disk of $\mathbb R^2$.

Consider the function $D^2\xrightarrow \psi D^2$ given by
$$x\mapsto R_{2\pi||x||^2}(x).$$

As the function $x\mapsto ||x||^2$ is $C^\infty$ on $D^2,$ so is $\psi$.

The function $x\mapsto R_{-2\pi||x||^2}(x)$ is $C^\infty$ and it is the inverse function of $\psi$, hence $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism.

Notice that $\psi\upharpoonright\partial D^2$ is the identity. Thus if $M$ is a surface, we can get a subset $D$ of $M$ diffeomorphic to $D^2$, and using $\psi$ we can get a diffeomorphism $D\rightarrow D$ which is not the identity, but it is the identity on the boundary of $D$. This function can be extended to a diffeomorphism of $M$ which is not the identity.

For the case $n\geq 3$  consider the function $D^n\rightarrow D^n$ given by 
$$x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto (R_{2\pi||x||^2}(x_1,x_2),x_3,\ldots,x_n),$$
and argue as before.